# Differences between not rendering a component from within the parent's render method and not rendering the component from its own render method?

Tags: performance, reactjs, components, render

My gut feeling is that choosing to not render a component from within the parent's `render` method has differences from choosing to not render the same component from within its own `render` method; at least from a behind the scenes point, since the perceived end result is the same.

Can someone explain if there are indeed differences and what are they?

Sorry for lack of code examples, I will add some when I have a normal computer available.

UPDATE:

For example, from inside the parent component's `render` method:

```
...
render() {
    return(
        <ParentComponent>
            {(this.state.renderSpecificChild) ? <SpecificChild /> : null}
            <SomeOtherChild />
        </ParentComponent>
    );
}
...
```

VS

from inside the child component's render method

```
...
render() {
    return(
        {(this.props.renderSelf) ? <div></div> : null}
    );
}
...
```

when the parent's `render` method looks like this

```
...
render() {
    return(
        <ParentComponent>
            <SpecificChild />
            <SomeOtherChild />
        </ParentComponent>
    );
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the major difference, is that when the parent controls whether to render the child or not, instead of the child itself, the component gets unmounted and, internally, React cleans things up. If the child itself decides whether to render something or not, all its methods etc remain in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. If you have the child component that is reusable somewhere else and needs to have the non rendering check then you would put it in the child component, otherwise if you you didn't want this check in another part of the app for this child you would make it more specific and just put it in the parent.

If you don't have this scenario at the moment then it doesn't matter at the moment which one you put it in. It should be easy to refactor later down the line if you need to change it.

Comment: I see. My question however is more in the lines of "what happens behind the scenes, what are the differences, behind the scenes, between these 2 approaches"? For example, are lifecycle methods for the component kept in memory in one case but not the other? I hope I clarified a little